# An experiment stays at 0% after 24 hours for a dataset of 13M rows

Tags: driverless-ai

My running experiment seems hung, for it still stays at 0% after 24 hours, showing messages "Detecting schemas..."  and "Waiting for information...".    The dial setting was 8-5-5.  The dataset size is about 8GB, 13M rows, 31 columns.

In the h2oai_experiment_name.log, I saw "max_rows = 151500000" and "max_rows_feature_evolution = 1520000".  Where can I find the meaning of these ?

Would these have anything to do with the hang ?  Would I have to edit config.toml or something like that to address the hang ?

Comment: hi nasica88, can you post the version of DAI you are using? thanks!

Comment: Sure.  It is 1.6.3 on Ubuntu 18.04 with CUDA 9.2.

Comment: if you turn down the dial settings to fastest 1/1/10 does it finish? have you seen it finish for less complex and time consuming settings? I would take a look at your logs and see if any further details are provided.

Comment: I had to abort it and re-run the same training.  It now worked.  Maybe a glitch ?  I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I had to abort it and re-run the same training. It now worked. Maybe a glitch ? I don't know.